# Data security in R shiny

Tags: r, security, shiny, shiny-server

I am working on a shiny app that calls an RData file with some user information in it. The code for the app and the RData file aren't going to be hosted anywhere besides wherever it is stored when you deploy an app to the shiny server. The RData file is just included in the same folder as the actual app code in an R project folder.

Before releasing the app, I would like to know how secure the data is - are there reasonable ways that someone using the app could somehow get access to the data?

Comment: I am not an expert on security.  I do know you can chmod 600 sensitive files to at the very least give them stricter permissions.

Comment: Some discussion on this subject here: https://mastering-shiny.org/scaling-security.html